Error 405 in Spring Security 6 with custom login page
package com.scm.configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final SecurityCustomUserDetailService securityCustomUserDetailService;

    SecurityConfig(SecurityCustomUserDetailService securityCustomUserDetailService){
        this.securityCustomUserDetailService = securityCustomUserDetailService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(securityCustomUserDetailService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize)->{
            //only auth user login access kar sakte hai
            authorize.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
            authorize.anyRequest().permitAll();
            
        });
        //form login se related configuration
        httpSecurity.formLogin((form)->{
            form
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .successForwardUrl("/user/dashboard")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password");            
        });
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}


<form method="post" th:action="@{'/authenticate'}">
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your email here" required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="password">Your password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required />
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>


package com.scm.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.scm.forms.UserForm;
import com.scm.helpers.Message;
import com.scm.helpers.MessageType;
import com.scm.services.UserService;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

import com.scm.entities.User;




@Controller
public class PageController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home"; // return in the name of page/html file located in templates folder
    }

    @GetMapping("/about")
    public String about(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("isAdmin",true);
        return "about";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/services")
    public String services() {
        return "services";
    }

    @GetMapping("/contact")
    public String contact(){
        return "contact";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model){
        UserForm userForm = new UserForm();
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        return "register";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }


  
    


    @PostMapping("/do-register")
    public String processRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute UserForm userForm,HttpSession session,BindingResult bindingResult){
        User user = User.builder()
        .name(userForm.getName())
        .email(userForm.getEmail())
        .password(userForm.getPassword())
        .about(userForm.getAbout())
        .phoneNo(userForm.getPhone())
        .roleList(List.of("ROLE_USER"))
        .build();
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "register";
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        Message message = Message.builder().content("Registration successful !").type(MessageType.green).build();
        session.setAttribute("message", message);
       
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
}

I was using my custom login page with above spring security config. I am getting the **Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported] **I didn't understand what's the problem, what is happening . Review it please.
I tried disabling csrf and adding csrf in custom csrf field but not working.

/login - for my custom login page
/authenticate - for processing authentication(as spring security 6 config)

I don't see processing of "/authenticate" endpoint in controller, is it processed? Sorry, I see

Looks like you should not call login form manually form controller, it will be done by Spring when you try access secured page. See the flow https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

There is also an example how to use custom login form, I hope it will help

I got something.
The error was caused by .successForwardUrl("/user/dashboard") of SecurityConfig class, i tried using .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/dashboard") which works absolutly fine.

successForwardUrl() uses a server-side forward, which means it forwards the request internally within the server. This keeps the
original HTTP method (e.g., POST) and request attributes intact. If
the target URL does not accept the original HTTP method (e.g., POST),
the server will return a 405 error. We can also use this by mapping
post request  to @PostMapping("/user/dashboard"), but make a note
URL will not change in this case.
defaultSuccessUrl() performs a client-side redirect using HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(), which results in a new GET
request to the target URL.

